# How to make grid layout using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make this layout:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxYFT.png)

I have this code:

```css
.tiles-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.tile {
  width: 21%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 61px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles-container">
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
  <div class="tile">name</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that there isn't space between items vertically. I could achive it by using margin-bottom, but i want the space to be equal on every side. Can you help, please?

Comment: Why not use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to make a grid layout?

Comment: `flex-grow:1;` then set a universal margin

Comment: @HereticMonkey i once heard that it is best to stick to one method of making layout (float, flex or grid). On my website i only use flexbox so that's way. I am not sure is it good practice to be honest :\

Comment: @ZohirSalak thank you it worked :)